# What's the point of a deep folder structure in Java (Maven)?

Tags: java, maven

I've inherited a Java (Maven) project at work. I'm not a Java developer, but the project is now mine, nonetheless.  When I clone (a la `git clone`) the repository, I notice the folder structure goes really deep before any .java files appear.  For instance, the folder structure looks like this:

```
project_name
 .git
 .idea
  src/
    main/
      java/
        org/
          bah/
            co/
              lab/
                zeus/
                  apimanager/
                    RestClient.java
```

I've googled around, trying to find out why the folder structure goes so deep.  After some research into Maven, my understanding is the default structure begins with **/src/main/java**.  So, I'm curious why the previous (now incommunicado) developer structured this repo (and many others) like this.  So as not to solicit opinion, please tell me: is there a technical reason the project is structured like this?  There are literally no other .java files outside of the `apimanager` folder, so what technical reason would there be to bury everything so deep?

Comment: Surely `RestClient.java` features a line at or near the top, with no other text above it that isn't a comment, that reads `package java.org.bah.co.lab.zeus.apimanager`. In Java, classes can be structured in packages, and said packages are structured in the file system as a series of nested folders.

Comment: Think of the packages as helping to classify the classes into categories.

Comment: Maybe it's time to start learning Java, starting with a lesson on [Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper The 'java' is part of maven's structure; the package statement would start with `org.`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Yes, you're right. Total brainfart on my part, and it's too late to edit my comment :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maven is a tool that has certain opinions on where things should go; a default configuration. You don't *have to* follow it, but not following this default configuration has three significant downsides:

- You do have to then configure maven to tell it about the alternative choices you made. Maven does not make this easy.
- Other java programmers generally assume the defaults. If you have a good reason to deviate, go for it, but 'I do not like it' is not a good reason, as it'll be pointlessly increasing the learning curve.
- The maven developers chose this structure as default for a reason. If you think it's a dumb reason, that's certainly possible and you may even be right, but then you're using a build tool written by folks who, (judging the book by its cover a little bit), according to you, make boneheaded choices about sane defaults. That's not a great place to be.

To explain each layer:

### `src`

Indicates that these are source files: Compiled and generated stuff should not be in here, and the *entire* `src` tree should be in version control. Contrast to e.g. `bin` or `build` containing build artefacts, `doc` containing documentation, and who knows what other directories you need for other relevant parts of a repo.

### `main`

A project can consist of multiple separately buildable artefacts and 'kinds' of product. For example, most projects include a bunch of code that exists solely for testing purposes (the unit tests). They live in `src/test`. The core product lives in `main`.
You can also have for example separate sources for an installer perhaps (`src/installer`), or a build plugin, or an annotation processor that needs to be built first and then it needs to be on classpath when compiling the `main` project, etcetera.

### `java`

There's such a thing as split language projects, where some of it is written in language A and some of it in language B. For its worth, I think this layer is bad design; A file ending in `.java` gives away how one is to 'compile it', and this goes for just about every source file that needs a compiler applied to it: The extension says just as much as a folder name of `java` ever could. To show you a common contrast: Many projects have `src/main/resources` as well as `src/main/java`: Resources are 'compiled' simply by copying them over: Imagine your app has a text file containing a list of all US states with all zipcodes used in each state. Or `png` files with icon images for a GUI app. Such files are just as much part of your main application as the class files would be and should end up in the same place (inside the `jar` file), but to 'compile' them, you just.. copy em, you don't run `javac` to do this. That's what this level is about: What tool should be used to turn source files into distributable aspects?

### `co/lab/zeus/apimanager`

This matches the java package structure. This is effectively a *requirement* applied by `javac` itself. The reason to use such a deeply nested package structure is simply because packages serve as namespaces: If there is a conflicting fully qualified name, **all hell breaks loose**: Java simply cannot handle this. Hence, java programmers ensure that such conflicts never happen by using a 'reverse domain name' structure: You'd stick your project in that package if you own the `zeus.lab.co` domain, thus ensuring nobody except other folks in your team who share control of that server could possibly be in conflict (and for those: They're in your team, talk to them to avoid conflict). For example, there are 3 different open source java projects all called spark. Had they all gone with `package spark;` (and thus, `src/main/java/spark/Main.java` as an example file), then for every java project you'd pick one of the 3: The other 2 you **can never use** in this project. Harsh, and pointless, which is why (almost) all java libraries use a reversed domain name as root package name, and then maven follows this package name in its directory structure because `javac` makes life extremely difficult if you don't do that.

That gets us to `project_name/src/main/java`.

### `org/bah`

You made that up for hyperbole. Nobody hosts a proj on `zeus.lab.co.bah.org`. But if they do: Talk to the management that decided to assign that whopper of a domain name to a team. It's on them, not on the author of this project.

Comment: LOL not hyperbole!  I obfuscated the folder names a bit, but the sheer depth count is honest!  I really appreciate your explanation, rzwitserloot!

Answer (score 2):

[Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) is a build and dependency management tool that helps develop your application and manage all the lifecycle of your development process such as *build*, *compilation*, *packaging*, *testing*, etc. through command lines.
There is a convention on how a Maven project is structured:

```
└───maven-project
    ├───pom.xml
    ├───README.txt
    ├───NOTICE.txt
    ├───LICENSE.txt
    └───src
        ├───main
        │   ├───java
        │   ├───resources
        │   ├───filters
        │   └───webapp
        ├───test
        │   ├───java
        │   ├───resources
        │   └───filters
        ├───it
        ├───site
        └───assembly
```

What is important to understand for the moment is the role a each files and folder and how to use Maven [commands](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-commands.html).

**`pom.xml`** : this file contains the structure and the information of your project, and your dependencies (external jars). This file is used by the commands you execute in Maven

**`src/main/java`** : contains your packages and your source code.

**`src/test/java`** : contains your test code

In your case, the structure of your project is due to the [package](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_packages.asp) name. Here, the name is `org.bah.co.lab.zeus.apimanager` and in Java a package is physically a nested group of folders. There is a package naming convention, but in most of the cases, it is up to you to choose the name you want to use.

As you are using IntelliJ IDEA, you can display your package with the options *Compact Middle Packages*.